# How to convert hours minutes to decimal after subtracting two dates in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm wondering how to get hh:mm in decimal after subtracting two dates in excel.

In other words, what formula should I use for `D2` using `A2` and `B2`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get it:

```
=HOUR(B2-A2)+MINUTE(B2-A2)/60
```

Comment: @pnuts I agree. Should be 1.35. 7:33 - 6:12 isn't 1:20 either in column C

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is just to subtract and multiply by 24

`=24*(B2-A2)`

format result cell as number

That works even across multiple days and would also include seconds if required